Deploy Serverless Typescript with Esbuild to AWS lambda
I am trying to deploy my serverless function. My deployment went through without any problem. However, I am encountering issues where AWS lambda console is looking for .mjs extension but the built code is in .js. I have to then manually update the extension for my deployment to work which defeats the purpose. I tried both the outExtension and the outFile config but no luck.
Here's my serverless.yml config:
...
build:
  esbuild:
    bundle: true
    minify: false
    external:
      - "uuid"
    exclude: "*"
    format: esm
    outExtension:
      ".js": ".mjs"

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
...

This is the basic code that I want to deploy:
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export const hello: any = async (event: any) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      id: uuidv4(),
      message: "Go Serverless v4! Your function executed successfully!",
    }),
  };
};

The compiled outcome is as follow:
|--handler.js // <=== AWS Lambda expecting handler.mjs
|--handler.js.map


On first glance I would say its related to format: esm try removing that param. I also dont think you need the outExtension param.
